# How to avoid nesting loops when comparing two strings?

Tags: javascript, loops, nested, comparison, processing-efficiency

I wrote this code that checks if one word can be made from the letters that are available in the other string. For example "wine" can be written using the letters contained in str1 = "kkwlaiern". However I'm looking for a more efficient way of doing this. So far this is my code:

```
 function scramble(str1, str2) {
  x =str1.split("");
  y =str2.split("");
  var h = 0;


 for (i=0, g = y.length; i<g; i++){
   for (j=0, f= x.length; j<f; j++){
         if (x[j]==y[i]){
           x.splice(j,1);
           h++;
           break;
           }}
 }
 if( h == y.length){
 return true;}
 else{return false;}
}
```

How can I write the same function without nesting "for" loops?

Answer (score 2):

Declare an array of size 26 and initialize it to 0 (index corresponding to the alphabets in English).

Read the bigger string using a `for` loop and increment it in the array:

```
a[str1[i]-'a']++
```

Next, read the smaller string and compare it with the values of the array:

```
if(a[str2[j]-'a']>0){
     a[str2[j]-'a']--;
}
```

If the above condition is satisfied for all the elements of `str2`, then `str2` can be derived from `str1`.

Comment: I'm still new to JS but I think you're treating a string as an array. How can you iterate through 'a'? I mean 'a' is a fixed value. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes in the above code snippet I have treated it as a char array.I didn't get your question regarding 'a' can you explain it .

Answer (score 0):

- Create an array of size 26. Each cell corresponds to a letter.
- Loop through `str1` and put 1 in the array for each letter in the string.
- Loop trough `str2`. If you find a letter that has 0 in the array - return false. If you looped through the whole string - return true

Answer (score 0):

It's better to just use a Regex

```
var str1 = 'eve'
var str2 = 'Whatever'
if(st2.match(str1.split('+') && str1.length === str2.length ){
     //handle true
}
```

Comment: A Regex will do the trick is letters in first string are sorted in a predictable pattern. In the particular case of an unsorted string, a Regex will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a bit, but here is my solution, turning array elements into property values inside a new Object. Improves efficiency since there's no need for looping through each element of both arrays.

```
function scramble(str1, str2) {
x= str1.split(""); y= str2.split("");
var arr = new Object();


for(i=0; x.length > i; i++){
arr[x[i]] = (arr[x[i]] || 0) +1;} *//counts occurrence of elements in x and stores them as values inside Object*

for(i =0; y.length > i; i++){ 
arr[y[i]] = (arr[y[i]] || 0)-1;*// reduce value (-1) if y[i] is found in Object*
if (arr[y[i]] < 0){ return false;}} *// returns false if y[i] wasn't found*

return true; *//otherwise returns true.*

}
```